# print whole variable contents if the number of lines are greater than N

Tags: awk

How to print all lines if certain condition matches.

Example:

```
echo "$ip"
this is a sample line
another line
one more
last one
```

If this file has more than 3 lines then print the whole variable.

```
I am tried:

echo $ip| awk 'NR==4' 
last one
echo $ip|awk 'NR>3{print}' 
last one

echo $ip|awk 'NR==12{} {print}' 
this is a sample line
another line
one more
last one

echo $ip| awk 'END{x=NR} x>4{print}'
```

Need to achieve this:

If this file has more than 3 lines then print the whole file. I can do this using `wc` and `bash` but need a one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Awk` as follows,

```
echo "$ip" | awk '{a[$0]; next}END{ if (NR>3) { for(i in a) print i }}'
one more
another line
this is a sample line
last one
```

you can also make the value `3` configurable from an `awk` variable,

```
echo "$ip" | awk -v count=3 '{a[$0]; next}END{ if (NR>count) { for(i in a) print i }}'
```

The idea is to store the contents of the each line in `{a[$0]; next}` as each line is processed, by the time the `END` clause is reached, the `NR` variable will have the line count of the string/file you have. Print the lines if the condition matches i.e. number of lines *greater than* `3` or whatever configurable value using.

And always remember to double-quote the variables in `bash` to avoid undergoing word-splitting done by the shell.

---

Using [James Brown's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown) useful comment below to preserve the order of lines, do

```
echo "$ip" | awk -v count=3 '{a[NR]=$0; next}END{if(NR>3)for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}'
this is a sample line
another line
one more
last one
```

Comment: That `for(i in a)` does not produce the output in original order but in a random order ([see me](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal)). Rather `{a[NR]=$1}END{if(NR>3)for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print ...}`.

Comment: @JamesBrown: Updated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do this (no echo, no pipe, no loops, etc.):

```
$ awk -v ip="$ip" 'BEGIN{if (gsub(RS,"&",ip)>2) print ip}'
this is a sample line
another line
one more
last one
```

Comment: If only you are answering _ahead_ of mine, 80% of my `awk` answers wouldn't be accepted ;)

Comment: :-). Honestly, I just don't understand why people jump at the first answer they get instead of giving it time to see what other answers they'll get. You'd be amazed how many times (not this time) I look at an accepted answer and think "Holy crap - there's a time-bomb!" but I can't waste my time posting comments and/or additional answers every time (unless it's something trivial like this one) as my feeling is after accepting an answer the OP has usually moved on and others looking at it in future will usually assume the accepted answer is the one they should also adopt.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk. First test files:

```
$ cat 3
1
2
3
$ cat 4
1
2
3
4
```

Code:

```
$ awk 'NR<4{b=b (NR==1?"":ORS)$0;next} b{print b;b=""}1' 3  # look ma, no lines
  [this line left intentionally blank. no wait!]
$ awk 'NR<4{b=b (NR==1?"":ORS)$0;next} b{print b;b=""}1' 4
1
2
3
4
```

Explained:

```
NR<4 {                     # for tghe first 3 records
    b=b (NR==1?"":ORS) $0  # buffer them to b with ORS delimiter
    next                   # proceed to next record
} 
b {                        # if buffer has records, ie. NR>=4
    print b                # output buffer
    b=""                   # and reset it
}1                         # print all records after that
```